# What's changed in the HTTP responses of play 2.4 -> 2.5

Tags: playframework-2.5

In the play framework 2.4, I had an app which served up CSV data, which was then read by another program.

For example;

```
  def allRegionsAction = Action.async {
    val theResult = for(
      result <- db.run(allRegions.result)
    ) yield (
        header +
        result.mkString("\n")
      )
    theResult.map(something => Ok(something))
  }
```

This worked fine for responses of arbitrary size. After updating to the play framework 2.5, the program reading the response now reads about 9000 rows of the table, and then gives up, closing the connection.

I've tried a few things; 
[How to properly serve csv data with play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418568/how-to-properly-serve-csv-data-with-play-framework)

But I'm stuck... My guess is something to do with the content-length header, but I'm stumped on how to correctly set it, and where. Event the HttpEntity.Strict response exhibits the same behaviour.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I never found the answer to this.

However, upgrading to 2.5.3 appeared to fix the problem...